# Converting ObsevableCollection foreach to lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

I am working on an `ObservableCollection`. Converting my code to  a  lambda produces an error.

This is my actual code .

```
foreach (var item in Query)
{
   userDetail.Add(new UserDatail(item.ID,item.Name, item.Address, item.City, item.Pin, item.Phone));
}
```

When I write it as a lambda, like this:

```
Query.ToList().ForEach(x => userDetail.Add(x.ID,x.Name,x.Address,x.City,x.Pin,x.Phone));
```

That gives me an error.

Thanks.

Comment: It would help to know what the error is.

Comment: Would it terribly inconvenience you to provide the error message that you see? I wouldn't bother you at all, but it was just today that my mind-reading machine broke down. Sorry :-(

Comment: From these short snippets, its hard to tell what you want. What does the unconverted code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error is a compiler error similar to "No overload for method 'Add' takes 6 arguments', it probably comes from the fact that you are not adding `UserDetail`s to your collection.

Your `ForEach` should look more like this:

```
Query.ToList().ForEach(item => userDetail.Add(new UserDatail(item.ID,item.Name, item.Address, item.City, item.Pin, item.Phone)));
```